# Name of this two pronged female DC power supply plug (looks like a pair of rectangular glasses)

Tags: electrical, cord-and-plug

**[Here's a YouTube video showing the plug](https://youtu.be/GtA9p8OkEEc?t=121)**. I'm referring to the plug that goes into the device, of course. Not the normal AC plug on the power supply unit itself.

[image]

I'm considering buying a device that uses an AC/DC power supply (the device in the video, in fact). However, the plug at the end of the power supply's cord is a little unusual and if something happens to the supply, I don't want it to render the device useless.

So I'm looking for either the possibility of buying a similar power supply, or an adapter which I could connect to a regular supply. But I don't know what this plug is called so I can't even search for it.

Comment: While I'm not familiar with that exact plug (and I think there's a good chance it's proprietary, despite its similarity to some more common plug types), keep in mind that if just the PSU dies but the plug is fine, you can always clip the plug off the dead PSU and splice it onto the wires of a new matching one -- I've often done this when confronted with unusual connectors.  With low voltage DC like this device, that's perfectly safe.

Comment: My thoughts on both counts exactly, Nate. It's not quite a standard PC power plug, and not quite an AC/DC converter plug for a laptop, but simple butt-splice crimp connectors (with or without heat-shrink tubing) make quick work of that kind of thing.

Comment: Grab one of the ["figure 8" plugs](https://www.google.com/search?q=figure+8+power+cord&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&sxsrf=ACYBGNSE9KZTIb_nXPXKdj8CMnLAobFgqQ:1578425132962&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig9urqm_LmAhUKAZ0JHVFdDVUQ_AUoAnoECA0QBA&biw=1841&bih=979) you probably have laying around and see how it fits.

Comment: I would *hope* that a figure-8 plug would not fit by default, because that's for full AC line voltage, not the low voltage DC your device requires.  However, if the rubber part is too big but the pin size is the same, since they're usually soft rubber, you could probably shave one down to fit with a knife if you needed to.

Comment: @NateS. I just found that out while searching Amazon for it. But if the original "glasses" plug gets ruined, I could get a "figure 8" plug, cut it, and as you mentioned, shave it to size. (Assuming, of course, that the distance between the prongs is the same as in the proprietary one).

Comment: Just make sure you keep the polarity correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a few listings for this plug that refer to this plug as a "Waeco Fridge Adapter".  It looks like the plug is used for 12vdc fridge and other thermoelectric cooling devices.  I'm not going to post a link because most of them are eBay listings that will expire soon, but that name should help you a lot.

[image: Waeco fridge adapter]

I found [this link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N9LQ5QC) on Amazon that might last a little longer, but it doesn't give a technical name for it either.

Looks like a good generic search term is "polarized 2 pin 12V DC plug for electric cooler boxes".

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's the standard for car coolers (at least from what I can see on Amazon.) +1.

Comment: @ispiro, I think the main takeaway is that this is a very common plug, so you shouldn't worry about losing/damaging one.

Comment: Nice find!  It looks like "Waeco plug" is a fairly generic name for it.  Aliexpress has it too: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32809783210.html